# Unclear about the definition of payoff in a mathematical statistics context

Tags: statistics

I highlighted the area of confusion.

1. The author uses payoff without defining it and I'm not sure where this is coming from or what it means.
2. I am not sure why the following is true - "Moreover, if they truly believe that $p = 2/5$ is correct, they would be willing to accept either side of the bet."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The author is trying to represent probability in terms of a gain in a game.

Compute the expected gain from the bet described: you receive 3 USD if the event $A$ happen, you lose 2 USD if it doesn't. $E[B]=p\times3+(1-p)\times(-2)=0$ for $p=\frac{2}{5}$. That describes a fair game (you don't make or lose on average).

As a side note, and in reality, psychologists and economists have show that we handle losses and gains differently, and you should use utility functions instead of outright gains.